# Is it possible to define a specific criterion prior to imputing missing values?

Tags: missing-data, data-imputation, filter

it's hard to summarise the problem in a question so I'll explain it here.
I have a variable called "Plant Species" that is missing a lot of values because of the sampling method used. For one method there are all the values, for the other none. The plant species are associated to another variable "Plot is Native", because certain species are found only on native plots and certain species only on non-native plots. This can be found by filtering the data by the sampling method without missing values. Following missing value imputation, however, this distinction is no longer true: some plants that are supposed to be only on native plots can also now be found on non-native plots (which is incorrect). My question is, is there a way to set a certain criterion that would prevent this prior to missing value imputation?
I've tried with KNNImputer and MissForest imputer and the problem is the same.
Thank you

Comment: If you want to do the imputation based on some specific rule, you simply need to write the code that does it.

Comment: How would I go about it? Using linear interpolation? Selecting only the Plot is Native column to impute the Plant Species column? Your statement doesn't really give me any ideas....

Comment: There are infinite ways how this can be done. It depends on the details of your data and the problem you are trying to solve. If you edit your question for more details, someone may be able to help, but it also can be the case that it's more complicated to be answered by a short answer on a Q&A site like this.